# Python regex: replace ignoring empty string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace a given pattern with regular expressions in Python, using `re`. Here is the piece of Python code I wrote:

```
import re

fname = './prec.f90'
f = open(fname)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    search = re.findall('([\d*]?\.[\d*]?)+?[^dq\_]', line)
    if search != []: 
        print('Real found in line #%d: ' %i)
        print search
        print('The following line:\n %s' %line)
        print('will be replace by:')
        newline = re.sub('([\d*]?\.[\d*]?)+?[^dq\_]', r'\g<1>d0\g<2>', line)
        print('%s' %newline)
```

And the `prec.f90` contains something like that (it is just an example, it does not means that all the strings I want to replace have the form `[x]_[yz] = ...;`):

```
  x_pr = 0.1; y_pr = 0.2; z_pr = 0.1q0
  x_sp = 0.1; y_sp = 0.1d0; z_sp = 0.1q0
  x_dp = 0.1; y_dp = 0.1d0; z_dp = 0.1q0
  x_qp = .1; y_qp = 0.1d0; z_qp = 0.1q0
  x_db = 0.; y_db = 0.1d0; y_db = 0.1q0
```

My goal is to modify all the pattern like `0.1`, `.1` and `0.`, to get something like `0.1d0`; I don't want to modify the other patterns. The problem is that `re.findall('[\d*]?\.[\d*]?)+?([^dq\_]')` matches the pattern I am looking for, but also returns an empty string for the other ones. Therefore, when I run this piece of code, it fails, being unable to replace match the first and second groups in the `re.sub()` for the empty strings.

I guess one solution would be to ignore empty string in the `re.sub`, or to have something like a conditional argument in it, but I could not figure out how.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is failing [subbing the empty string] because you made all the components optional with `*`. What is the minimum string that will be on a line that you want to replace? If it is `.x` then change the second `\d*` to `\d+`

Comment: Problem is they can have the 3 forms I mentioned: `x.y`, `.y` and `x.`. I want (and need) to cover all these cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with this piece of code that is working as intended:

```
import re

fname = './prec.f90'
f = open(fname)
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
# If there was no end of the line character (\n) we would need to check if 
# this is the end of the line (something like ([^dq\_0-9]|$)
regex = re.compile(r'(\d*\.\d*)([^dq\_0-9])')
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    search = regex.findall(line)
    if search != []: 
        print('Real found in line #%d: ' %i)
        print search
        print('The following line:\n %s' %line)
        print('will be replace by:')
        newline = regex.sub(r'\g<1>d0\g<2>', line)
        print('%s' %newline)
```

I first came up with the more complicated regex `([\d*]?\.[\d*]?)+?[^dq\_]` because else I always match the first part of any string ending with `d`, `q` or `_`. It seemed to be due to the fact that `\d*` was not greedy enough; to add `0-9` in the "ignore" set solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the `sub` as

```
>>> str="x_db = 0.; y_db = 0.1d0; y_db = 0.1q"
>>> re.sub(r'(0\.1|\.1|0\.)(?=;)', r'\g<1>0d0', str)
'x_db = 0.0d0; y_db = 0.1d0; y_db = 0.1q'
```

The regex `(0\.1|\.1|0\.)(?=;)` would match `0.1`, `.1` and `0.` followed by as `;`

Comment: Please read my edit, the strings I want to replace have a more general form, this was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

```
(x_[a-zA-Z]{2}\s*=)\s+[^;]+
```

Try this.Replace by `\1 0.1d0`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/qZ6sE3/2

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(x_[a-zA-Z]{2}\s*=)\s+[^;]+')
test_str = u"x_pr = 0.1; y_pr = 0.2; z_pr = 0.1q0\nx_sp = 0.1; y_sp = 0.1d0; z_sp = 0.1q0\nx_dp = 0.1; y_dp = 0.1d0; z_dp = 0.1q0\nx_qp = .1; y_qp = 0.1d0; z_qp = 0.1q0\nx_db = 0.; y_db = 0.1d0; y_db = 0.1q0"
subst = u"\1 0.1d0"

result = re.sub(p, subst, test_str)
```

Comment: The string I want to replace can have a much general form than `x_[a-Z] = ...`. The test in my question is what it is: a simple test :)

Comment: nope, because I don't want to modify only the "0.1" but actualy any real number, and I don't have all my expressions ending with a semi-column. and I want to replace the original string by its value, not a dummy `0.1`.